# "Some packages could not be installed" error while installing python3-pip on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management

When I run the commannd `sudo apt install python3-pip`on Ubuntu 16.04 I got these errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2) but 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching a lot, I was finally able to install pip3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine by simply running these commands

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

Answer (score 13):

Just remove the `python-pip-whl` package and try again:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip-whl
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Be aware that actually removes Python2 pip (if you happen to require both installations in parallel).  I solved OP's issue by first uninstalling python2 pip, then installing python3 pip, then finally reinstalling python2 pip, in that order.

Comment: not work for some of us.  nothing change

Answer (score 5):

You have broken packages so use these steps:

1. Fix broken packages:

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```
2. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```
3. Now install normally:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip
   ```
4. Check if it installed:

   ```
   pip3 --version
   ```

That should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Install the dependencies you see in the message (You can specify the version to install for the python-pip-whl package with an equal sign):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip-whl=8.1.1-2 python3-dev python3-wheel
```

Then try again:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Answer (score -1):

After searching a lot finally this works for me

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then install pip3 with this command:

```
sudo aptitude install python3-pip
```

Comment: This worked for me too

Answer (score -1):

After reading 100s of solutions, at last I found that what I was missing was:

In **Software and Updates**

Check the option:

*Canonical - supported free and open source software (main)*

Comment: that should be on by default - most important packages are in that repository.